# javac cannot be found - CLASSPATH/Path/JAVA_HOME set for JDK on Windows 7 64-Bit

Tags: windows-7, path, classpath, java, javac

I've looked in numerous threads here and on Google and cannot find a solution.

I've installed the latest version of Java JDK (1.6.0_26) on my 64-bit Windows 7. I've added the file path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26" to JAVA_HOME, and added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin" to the CLASSPATH and PATH variables. I've restarted my machine. But, I when I go to to run javac -version from the command line, I receive the error

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Please let me know what I should do! I'm attempting to use Appcelerator's Titanium but it requires a valid path for javac. Thanks!

For reference, here is my PATH variable.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\
Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Fil
es\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shar
ed\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:
\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (
x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\
OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\WIDCO
MM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64; C:\
Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;
```

Comment: Well, why the extra space (" ")?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin" is indeed correct, that extra space was the answer! Thank you very much, I knew I was doing everything correct which is why it was bugging me that it wasn't working. Well, almost everything correct ;)

Comment: It's annoying when little things are such a nuance! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error is just what it says. `javac` is not found on the path.** (This issue has nothing to do with Java, rather windows cannot find the unqualified executable in the current path or search "PATH" paths.)

Locate the `javac` file manually. Verify it can be run with the found path.

Ensure the path is put in PATH environment variable correctly (it *must* be separated from other entries with a semi-colon (`;`)). The CLASSPATH is not relevant here. Depending on how PATH is set, it may require *restarting* the windows shell (e.g. log out and log back in). Verify the new PATH is correct with `echo %PATH%` from a console.

Run `javac` and verify it is executed.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I mentioned, I've already restarted the windows shell. The PATH variable is set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin", and I've confirmed that with echo %PATH%. Exploring this file path does lead me to javac.exe.

Comment: @John **Chances are that is not possible -- read all the steps again**. Paste the result of `echo %PATH%` *and* the *full path which can be used* to run `javac`. For instance, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk\1.6.0_26\bin\javac" (hmm, **bin**? In any case, *whatever works there*) Either that, or you have found an elusive regression bug in Windows ;-)

Comment: Added the contects of echo %PATH% to my original post.

Comment: @John Added a question to the post ;-) I suspect that will solve it. In any case, the fully qualified executable path is the last piece of the puzzle...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I set the path in command line:

> set path = "c:/...."

but it was not recognized as path, than I checked my Windows type (x64) and Java type (x64). Then I set the path manually in system variables in the properties of My computer and re-opened the cmd prompt, it worked.

Comment: I can't find anything in this answer that is not contained in the existing answer already.